# Missing cxcore110d.dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, dll, opencv

When I try to run a opencv hellow world program I get an error saying that the cxcore110d.dll file is not installed and that I need to reinstall the program, but the dll is C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV\bin. Any one know who to fix this? The folder is referenced (maybe thats the wrong term) in the solution that came with opencv 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenCV\bin` to your system path. Right-click `My Computer` then select `Advanced`. Click the `Environment Variables` button and double click `Path` in the `System variables` box. Add a `;` and append it to the end of the existing path.